# Is it safe to embed an ID token within a JWT token?

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-active-directory, authorization

I'm new to JWT and authorization of micro-services in general.  We are using Azure to do our authentication for an application backed by micro-services.  However, we are using a separate home grown micro-service to do RBAC/ABAC authorization.  I was thinking that the general scheme to use in order to secure all of the micro-services is to use JWT.  My thought was that once authenticated and I have an Azure ID token, that ID token would be passed within a JWT token to my authorization service in order to get an authorization token from my authorization service. It would use the Azure ID token to validate that the user actually authenticated themselves by validating the ID token and the generate my application access token to use from then on.  In general, is it safe/secure to pass around an ID token within a JWT payload?  Hopefully that all makes sense.

Comment: More typically, obtaining authorization rights would _not_ include any kind of further credentials.  Rather, once authenticated, your server would just use authz to figure out _what_ the user is allowed to in your application.

Comment: Right Tim, I totally get and agree in principal with that.  The way I would like to do it is have authentication go through the service we build and the authentication request be forwarded to Azure AD.  Then my service would just construct a single token that would be used.  However, because of the way Azure authentication works, I don't know that a service acting as a proxy for authentication will work.  It it does, that is how I would do it and a secondary call for an access token wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Regarding how _safe_ it is to pass the ID inside the JWT, it should be reasonably safe assuming you are using SSL.  For extra protection, you could encrypt the JWT before sending.

Comment: Hmm. I would suggest you think one more time about using authorization within the microservice world. I rather would suggest thinking about private networking / closed environment - like Kubernetes - or build based on it Microsoft AKS (Azure Kubernetes Service) where you have only a few, fully controlled, authorized endpoints. Keep in mind that authz operations takes also a processing time.